# ModuleNotFoundError when trying to use Twilio from Python

Tags: python, twilio, modulenotfounderror

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named
> 'twilio.rest.api.v2010.account.sip.domain.auth_types.auth_registrations_mapping.auth_registrations_credential_list_mapping'

I've encountered this error while following a tutorial step-by-step using Twilio to send myself a text message via Python. This is only the second time I have used Twilio, and it worked fine the first time, granted a much simpler code. Can anyone tell me why I have encountered this error while the tutorial did not and how it can be fixed? (I have already made sure that I got the authentications correctly) I am new in programming so I may not be familiar with some of the jargons like `pip install Twilio` and such

This is the short version of the code if it helps:

---

```
from twilio.rest import Client 

formatted_articles = [f"Headline: {article['title']}\nBrief: {article ['description']}" for article in three_articles]
   
client = Client(account_sid, auth_token)
    
for article in formatted_articles:
    message = client.messages.create(
        body=article,
        from_=Twilio_number,
        to=Own_number
    )
```

---

Comment: Generally if you find ModuleNotFoundError it is related to uninstalled dependency
Fix is - `pip install {packagename}`

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

In order to use the Twilio Python module you will need to install it in your project. To do that you should use your terminal application to navigate to your project directory and then run the command:

```sh
pip install twilio
```

To read more about this check out the Python documentation on [installing Python modules](https://docs.python.org/3/installing/index.html) and the [Twilio documentation on using the Twilio Python module](https://www.twilio.com/docs/libraries/python).

Answer (score 0):

open powershell as admin and run this command

```
New-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\FileSystem" `
-Name "LongPathsEnabled" -Value 1 -PropertyType DWORD -Force
```

after that install the twilio module again
`pip3 install twilio`